# Reconnecting Bluetooth device via PowerShell

Tags: windows, powershell, bluetooth

I've found the following question:
[How to connect and disconnect a Bluetooth device with a PowerShell script on Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53642702/how-to-connect-and-disconnect-a-bluetooth-device-with-a-powershell-script-on-win/64085710#64085710)

Concerning the second answer "xzion14!",
I found the script to be very useful.
Is there an option to reconnect the same device, which I just got disconnected by the script? I cannot find the corresponding command.
With the MAC address I just picked, it should be somehow possible to find the device (again), when put into pairing-mode and re-pair it?

Edit:
I found the following:
„BLUETOOTH_DEVICE_INFO“

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/bluetoothapis/nf-bluetoothapis-bluetoothauthenticatedeviceex

Don‘t know how to modify it, though.
Edit 2: original code

```
$Source = @"
   [DllImport("BluetoothAPIs.dll", SetLastError = true, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
   [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U4)]
   static extern UInt32 BluetoothRemoveDevice(IntPtr pAddress);
   public static UInt32 Unpair(UInt64 BTAddress) {
      GCHandle pinnedAddr = GCHandle.Alloc(BTAddress, GCHandleType.Pinned);
      IntPtr pAddress     = pinnedAddr.AddrOfPinnedObject();
      UInt32 result       = BluetoothRemoveDevice(pAddress);
      pinnedAddr.Free();
      return result;
   }
"@
Function Get-BTDevice {
    Get-PnpDevice -class Bluetooth |
      ?{$_.HardwareID -match 'DEV_'} |
         select Status, Class, FriendlyName, HardwareID,
            # Extract device address from HardwareID
            @{N='Address';E={[uInt64]('0x{0}' -f $_.HardwareID[0].Substring(12))}}
}
################## Execution Begins Here ################
$BTDevices = @(Get-BTDevice) # Force array if null or single item
$BTR = Add-Type -MemberDefinition $Source -Name "BTRemover"  -Namespace "BStuff" -PassThru
Do {
   If ($BTDevices.Count) {
      "`n******** Bluetooth Devices ********`n" | Write-Host
      For ($i=0; $i -lt $BTDevices.Count; $i++) {
         ('{0,5} - {1}' -f ($i+1), $BTDevices[$i].FriendlyName) | Write-Host
      }
      $selected = Read-Host "`nSelect a device to remove (0 to Exit)"
      If ([int]$selected -in 1..$BTDevices.Count) {
         'Removing device: {0}' -f $BTDevices[$Selected-1].FriendlyName | Write-Host
         $Result = $BTR::Unpair($BTDevices[$Selected-1].Address)
         If (!$Result) {"Device removed successfully." | Write-Host}
         Else {"Sorry, an error occured." | Write-Host}
      }
   }
   Else {
      "`n********* No devices foundd ********" | Write-Host
   }
} While (($BTDevices = @(Get-BTDevice)) -and [int]$selected)
```