# How to Connect a Bluetooth or Audio device in Windows PowerShell?

Tags: windows, powershell, automation, admin

I'm trying to automate connecting my AirPods so I don't have to manually do it each time I log on to my machine for a meeting. Windows remembers my AirPods since they were previously paired. I don't need to automate the pairing, but I'd like to automate the following (scribbling out actual names):

1. Clicking connect here.

[image: Windows Bluetooth & other devices]

2. Selecting the audio device here:

[image: Selecting Audio Output Device]

From my initial searching, I found this post:

[How to connect and disconnect a Bluetooth device with a PowerShell script on Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53642702/how-to-connect-and-disconnect-a-bluetooth-device-with-a-powershell-script-on-win)

I am running powershell as Admin. At first, I attempted the steps in the aforementioned post as-is (which filters for Bluetooth -- I found friendlyname by calling Get-PnpDevice with nothing after it, and just reading through the list), but I realized after playing with it and not seeing anything, that it's actually returning two devices - presumably one for each headphone:

```
$device = Get-PnpDevice -class Bluetooth -friendlyname "AirPods Pro Avrcp Transport"
Enable-PnpDevice -InstanceId $device.InstanceId -Confirm:$false


PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> $device
```

returns the following:

[image: Return from Enable-PnpDevice]

That's okay because the [MSDN documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/pnpdevice/enable-pnpdevice?view=windowsserver2019-ps) says one can input a string[] for InstanceId, but ultimately running Enable on these bluetooth devices Ids did nothing for me. So then I realized, the device shows up as Audio in the image above, and ran the following:

```
$device = Get-PnpDevice -class AudioEndpoint -friendlyname "Headphones (AirPods Pro Stereo)"
Enable-PnpDevice -InstanceId $device.InstanceId -Confirm:$false
```

Which returns the following:

[image: PowerShell Error Message]

I don't know what to make of the error messages:

CategoryInfo: NotSpecified: (Win32_PnPEntity...}.{EB5535DA...):ROOT\cimv2\Win32_PnPEntity)[Enable-PnpDevice], CimException
FullyQualifiedErrorId : HRESULT 0x80041001,Enable-PnpDevice

I'm out of ideas and can't find anything from searching. Any ideas or info?

**EDIT:**
I have found that if I manually do step 1. above, the error message goes away, but I don't really see a change in Windows (so similar behavior to running the Bluetooth InstanceIds)

Comment: Had the same problem, and found that windows shortcut Win+K opens the window with bluetooth devices

Comment: hmmm yeah that's probably equivalent to writing a script to automate it.